# Plotting with numpy and pylab

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have some data, that I have loaded up into `numpy`, I do not have a `csv` or any file loaded up with the range of dates I need, however I know what this array length is.

Currently I am just doing this to print up a simple graph:

```
t = numpy.arange(0.0, len(data), 1)
pylab.plot(t, data)
```

Would it be possible to replace `t` here so that I can specify a start and end date and it would print the actual date? Say, I have 365 days in my dataset, it would give the plot actually dates such as DD/MM/YYYY , 1/1/1999.1/2/1999.....12/31/1999?